# Can string pooling be corrupted or confused by use of unsafe C# code?

Tags: c#, string, clr, unsafe

If I manipulate a managed C# string in place (for example, reverse its characters) by using pointers in an `unsafe` code block or method, can that unsafe implementation confuse or corrupt the .NET string pooling mechanisms?

The proposed string being manipulated is created in managed code and passed to an unsafe method to be manipulated.

Example of this scenario:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string s = "this is a test";
    UnsafeReverse(s);
    Console.WriteLine(s); // displays "tset a si siht"
    // assume more managed strings are created and used along with the affected s. 
}

static unsafe void UnsafeReverse(string str) {
    int len = str.Length;

    fixed (char* pStr = str) {
        char* p1 = pStr;
        char* p2 = pStr + len - 1;

        char tmp;
        while (p1 < p2) {
            tmp = *p1;
            *p1 = *p2;
            *p2 = tmp;
            ++p1; --p2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  Just write it like this to see the damage:

```
    static readonly string DontMessWithStrings = "this is a test";

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string s = "this is a test";
        UnsafeReverse(s);
        Console.WriteLine(DontMessWithStrings);
    }
```

> [Edit by OP] The result of displaying `DontMessWithStrings` is **"tset a
>   si siht"** even though that variable is never directly touched by the string manipulation code!

Comment: I know the original string is reversed (effectively changing an immutable managed object) but will that mess up string pooling "under the hood"? I'm not sure how to prove that.

Comment: Yes, the interned string is thoroughly messed up.  The snippet proves it.  What is the point of this exercise?

Comment: That's the perfect example! I originally misinterpreted the result.  Thank you.